# const char* not found in map find

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, char, constants

I have a small program, I am trying to search for a particular string in the map, I get correct result if I pass static const string "us" to find but it doesn't work if I copy a string to pointer. 
I somehow think that it is trying to compare the address of the string that is passed. I am planning to get rid of std::string from due to some reason.

```
using namespace std;

static struct MarketLang {
    const char* market;
    const char* lang;
} market_lang[] = {
    {"us",  "all"},
    {"el",  "en,fr,it,de,es"},
    {"xx",  "na"},
};

class MarketLangMap {
    map<const char*, MarketLang *> table;
    public:
    MarketLangMap() {
        int TOTAL_MARKET_INFO = sizeof(market_lang)/sizeof(MarketLang);
        for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_MARKET_INFO; i++) {
            table[market_lang[i].market] = market_lang+ i;
        }
    }

    MarketLang *operator[](const char* s) {
        if (table.find(s) != table.end()) {
            return table.find(s)->second;
        } else {
            return table.find("xx")->second;
        }
    }
};


int
main()
{

   MarketLangMap *m = new MarketLangMap();
   const char* r = "us";
   char* p = new char(10);
   strcpy(p, "us");
   std::cout<<(*m)["us"]->lang <<std::endl;``
   std::cout<<(*m)[r]->lang <<std::endl;
   std::cout<<(*m)[p]->lang <<std::endl;

}
```

Expected output:
all
all
all

enter code here

Actual output:
all
all
na

Comment: You want to use std::string and not char const* in the map as the former will properly compare the two strings (i.e. implements a less-than operator) whereas the latter would just compare the pointers themselves and not the string contents.

Comment: Alternatively, you could supply your own binary predicate as the third template parameter to [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) that can compare your keys.

Comment: I agree, but is there a way to do without std::string ? How was it done in C world (I know map is not in C world)?

Comment: If you want a C solution, why did you tag this question C++?  Heck, why did you write your program in C++ to begin with?

Comment: @user2337805: Actually, that's exactly it.  `map` expects a key that obeys value semantics, wheras maps in C usually didn't.  The way you're using those strings is also not obeying value semantics.  Luckily, `map` can handle those cases as well, if you pass it a custom binary predicate.

Comment: Well my program was already written in C++, we had some issues with string usage due to performance. Is there any alternative solution to this? Is there any performance overhead of using string in this code?

Comment: Looking at the code you show, one of the issues is the use of too much `new` -- this isn't Java! Whenever you write `new`, you are probably doing it wrong. Whenever you write `delete`, you are very surely wrong. That said, you want to use a map<string,string>, it shouldn't cause your performance problem. However, you want to avoid running find() on a map twice instead of keeping and storing the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::map` is using strict weak ordering criterion indicated by its internal comparison object, which is defaulted to the `std::less`.

`std::less` will not treat `char*` arguments as a string, it will just see them as a pointers, and it will just check if one pointer is less than the other.

However, you can (but I guess you should use `std::string` to avoid mixing C and C++), create new class for comparing `char*` arguments, treating them as strings:

```
#include <cstring>

struct ConstCharStarComparator
{
  bool operator()(const char *s1, const char *s2) const
  {
    return strcmp(s1, s2) < 0;
  }
};

map<const char*, MarketLang *, ConstCharStarComparator> table;
```