# map::find() cannot find an existing key

Tags: visual-c++

I'm just trying to use the standard `std::map`, and I'm having troubles.  I remembered to include the headers, and here is my declaration:

```
std::map<const char *, UINT> boneList;
```

I've  filled it in with some data, but when I try to find a value like this:

```
std::cout << boneList.find("Bind_Spine1")->second;
```

But instead of printing a number, an error pops during runtime: "map/set iterator not derefernciable".

But if I do this:

```
std::cout << boneList["Bind_Spine1"];
```

Everything works just fine. Why the find() is returning end() when `operator[]` is not?   I am using visual studio 13

Comment: possible duplicate of [const char\* not found in map find](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310565/const-char-not-found-in-map-find)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boneList["Bind_Spine1"]` will add an item to the map if doesn't exist. `boneList.find("Bind_Spine1")` will not do that.

Change the key in the map to `std::string`. That should fix the problem. When you use `char const*` as the key of the map, it will all seem confusing. In C/C++, if you have

```
char const* ap = "abcd"; 
char const* bp = "abcd";
```

Then it's not guaranteed that `a == b`. However if you use

```
std::string a = "abcd"; 
std::string b = "abcd";
```

Then it is guaranteed that `a == b`.

Comment: Change the key in the map to `std::string`. That should fix the problem. When you use `char const*` as the key of the map, it will all seem confusing. In C/C++, if you have `char const* ap = "abcd"; char const* bp = "abcd";`, a != b. However if you use `std::string a = "abcd"; std::string b = "abcd";`, then a == b.

Comment: @RSahu: Technically `ap` and `bp` might or might not compare equal.

Comment: @MooingDuck you are right. I fixed the answer to reflect that.